# Removal of white noise from a signal, in frequency domain using low pass filter

Tags: java, signal-processing, lowpass-filter

**Environment**

Hi, I have an 128 point array which on plotting looks like this

[image: Signal With Noise]

I want to remove noise from this Signal and make signal something like

[image: Signal after filtering white noise]

For this my plan is to convert the signal in `frequency domain` and use  a `low pass filter.`

> Note - I am able to Convert the raw signal in frequency domain which
>   gives me two arrays of length 128(one is `*frequency plot*` and one is
>   `*phase plot*`). I am also able to recover the original signal using these two arrays. (`DFT & IDFT`).

**Problem**

Now I want to filter the noise from Signal. I am using `JAVA` as an programming language and  [this link](http://www.source-code.biz/dsp/java/)/ [this link](http://www.source-code.biz/dsp/java/apidocs/biz/source_code/dsp/filter/IirFilterDesignExstrom.html) provides a library for implementing `IIR Filters`. But I don't know what `cutoff frequency` should i use?

Also If I get `Filter coefficients` using above then  how to implement this filter?(Please explain theoretically)

I want to use a `butterworth lowpass filter.`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about DSP rather than programming DSP.

Comment: @Raedwald , Can you please explain What is programming? Because as far I know, programming is about converting logic to a particular language and the question is all about logic.

Answer (score 2):

So, linear filtering alone won't suffice; I took your signal picture, converted it back to a sequence of numbers, assigned an arbitrary time scale, and plotted it in time and frequency domain (plot 1-3):

[image: Plots]

Then I tried to find a filter that at least cancels most of your noisy peaks. Notice how that smoothed out the edges of the rectangular pulse in plot 4.

You might, however, apply a threshold after the filter and get your desired signal shape.

Comment: Hi @Marcus , thanks for your response, pulse in plot 4 will do my job. Can you please explain what cutoff frequency you choose for filtering?

Comment: @AdiTiwari: I forgot. Just go ahead and try some.